# Conditional react.js render is throwing an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a react.js app I have a `Tip` component that uses the Tether library, as a mixin, to allow it to attach to some other component that requires a tip.  This works great, however I am a little confuses on how to remove the tip when the user clicks the close link.

After some reading around it seems that the best practice is, from the tip component, call a passsed in method from the parent, that will not render the component on the next pass.  Unfortunately, when I do this I get an error message saying:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: processUpdates(): Unable to find child 2 of element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated
```

The first question is, whether there is a better way to insert the tip?  If you checkout the `getTip()` method that seems pretty ugly to do a conditional insertion of the component.

The second question is to why the error mentioned above is occuring.

Thanks for any help.

Here is the code:

#### parent component

```
React.createClass({

    getTip: function() {
        if (!this.state.showTip) return React.createElement('div', null, '');

        return React.createElement(Tip, {
            closeText: 'Got it!',
            destroy: this.removeTip,
            attachment: 'top center',
            targetAttachment: 'bottom center'
          },
          'Click outer arrows to skip by the week and inner arrows to skip by the day.');
    },

    removeTip: function() {
      this.setState({showTip: false});
    },

    render: function() {
        var tip = this.getTip();

        return (
          <div className="page">
            <header>
              <div className="dates__header__details">
                <!-- stuff -->

                {tip}
              </div>
              ...   
})
```

#### Tip component

```
var React = require('react');
var Tether = require('../tether/tether');

var Tip = React.createClass({

  mixins: [Tether],

  propTypes: {
    destroy: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  },

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      isVisible: true
    }
  },

  remove: function() {
    this.setState({isVisible: false});
    setTimeout(function() {
      this.props.destroy();
    }.bind(this), 500);
  },

  render: function() {
    // ...

    return (
      <div className={classList}>
        {this.props.children}

        <div className="tip__close" onClick={this.remove}>{this.props.closeText}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

});
```

#### Tether component

```
var React = require('react');
var T = require('../../../../../bower_components/tether/tether');

var Tether = {

  propTypes: {
    attachment: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    targetAttachment: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var el = this.getDOMNode();

    var tether = new T({
      target: el.parentNode,
      element: el,
      attachment: this.props.attachment,
      targetAttachment: this.props.targetAttachment
    });

    this.setState({'tether': tether});
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    var t = this.state.tether;
    t.destroy();
  }
};

module.exports = Tether;
```

Comment: may i know how the function `this.removeTip` designed?

Comment: It is setting the state value `isVisible` to false.  I have added it to the above code.

Comment: Please include enough code to make a reproducible demo.  That includes the tether mixin.

Comment: The Tether module is not part of the problem, so it can be removed from the mixins, although I have added it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [react docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#stateful-children) hiding elements is the suggested approach.